# Como traducir un queryset a subquery en django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, sql

Este es mi problema quiero agrupar por un campo el cual es un resultado de un annotate, pero no lo logro hacer.

```
from django.db.models import Max, Sum
queryset = queryset.values('period', 'cell').annotate(x=Max('total'))
result = queryset.values('period').annotate(result=Sum('x'))
```

**datos de ejemplo:**

```
period   cell   total

1         2       40
1         2       41
2         3       23
1         4       44
```

**Primer query**

```
queryset = queryset.values('period', 'cell').annotate(x=Max('total'))

period   cell     x
1         2       41
2         3       23
1         4       44
```

**Resultado esperado en la segunda query**

```
period   result
1          85
2          23
```

Buscando información , encontre que se puede hacer con subqueries  pero no lo logro hacer, si alguien tiene otra forma de hacerlo, sin usar un  **for** tambien se lo agradezco.

Comment: Lo que veo es el orden en que haces las cosas, creo que antes de usar el método `values` deberías pasar el `annotate` porque si no, estás excluyendo tu columna de `total`

Comment: O sea, según tu descripción dices que no logras agrupar por medio de una columna a la cual le haces annotate, y esa columna es `total`. Pero al hacer primero el `values` y luego el `annotate` estás excluyendo esa columna

Comment: @GermanAlzate, es decir, no funciona ni pasandole en el values.

Comment: revisa esto: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/12/06/how-to-create-group-by-queries.html

Comment: @Tegito123, Es un buen ejemplo pero no me sirve para lo que estoy haciendo